# Check link destination vs. url

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink

I already asked a similar question which led to more problems along the way.

I have a navbar with drop down menus that reveal on hover. I have "global links" to pages like "Home", "Sample-Page" or "Contact". On hover some of them reveal a drop down that links to anchor of the specific page. I want to use a smooth scroll script to jump from anchor to anchor. Here's an image to illustrate the situation.

[image]

Right now, I'm using this script:

```
$('.sub-menu .current-menu-item a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        target = $('#' + target.split('#')[1]);
        if( target.length ) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

As you can see, it relies on CSS-classes to limit its functionality to the current-page (CSS-class is assigned by PHP). This means if I'm on "Sample-Page" and I click on the link "/sample-page#anchor1" the page smoothly scrolls to that anchor. However, if I'm on "Sample-Page" and click "/contact#anchor1", the link directs me only to "Contact" but completely ignores the anchor.

For the jump between pages (page1 to page2 or page1 to page2#anchor) smooth scrolling makes absolutely no sense, so it only needs to be activated in those cases when you're already on the page with the anchors.

Somehow, my script needs to check on which page you are.

It also has to differ between these cases:
When a link is clicked, check

- if it links to an anchor on the same page -> run smooth scroll script
- if it links to an anchor on another page -> don't run script, jump to the anchor
- if it links to a page without an anchor -> don't run script, jump to the page

I hope you understand my problem. I would really appreciate any help!

Keep in mind that my links in the navbar look like this "/contact#anchor1" or "/sample-page#anchor2".

And here is the fiddle for you, so you can work with what I already have: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paelzersebbi/LmLRF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using `.hash` which returns the hash fragment only. Something like this (explained in code comments):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2s6MK/1/***

```
$('.test').on('click', function (event) {
    var h = this.hash; // get the hash fragment
    var t = $(h); // get any element using hash fragment as selector
    if (t.length > 0) { // if there are any elements with the id same as hash
        event.preventDefault(); // then prevent the default behavior
        $('html, body').animate({ // and start animating the scroll
            scrollTop: t.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    /*
        If there are no elements with the same id as the hash, 
        it means it belongs to another page. 
        then we do not preventDefault and hence the normal jump to page.
    */
});
```

**Edit**: (I overlooked the fact that there could be anchors with same name across pages and also got confused by fiddle as the anchor page name prefix does not match the current page location):

You could also try this:

```
$('.test').on('click', function (event) {
    var h = $(this.hash);
    var t = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[0]; // get the page name from href
    var l = window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g,""); // get the pathname from location
    if (t == l) { // if pathname matches the href page name
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: h.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The above code cannot be tested in fiddle.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I tried your script but it still ignores the anchor when I jump between pages. I it a problem, that my links don't have any class at all... I refer to them by ".submenu a"... is this valid? Or maybe the the link information is lost...?

Comment: If see my fiddle, you will notice that there is one anchor on the top which takes you to a w3c page at a specific anchor point. So, it works there should be not problem with that.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't in my case and I don't know why. I suspect that there is a problem with the CSS-class. My `<a href="...">`-tags have no class. I didn't make that clear in the fiddle... sorry.

Comment: Hmmm.. @paelzer. I also think I got confused by the fiddle and made a small fundamental mistake. The anchors have the same name across pages, so my logic will fail in those cases.

Comment: @paelzer: I have added the edit to the answer. And yes, absence of class shouldn't matter. Your selector is correct.

Comment: Hey, doesn't matter. I made one too. My navbar used the wrong links: I used "/sample-page#test" which doesn't work. However, "/sample-page/#test" works just fine. Also, in my example the anchors have the same name, but in the real page they are not the same.

Comment: @paelzer: Good that you could get it to work. But, that is a bit strange because the trailing "/" shouldn't be a problem. Check these two links: (1) http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#standardisation-URI-queries ; and (2) http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags#standardisation-URI-queries .

Comment: I'm wondering as well, maybe something else is interfering with the script... idk. BTW... in your second script the smooth scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: @paelzer: Thanks. I couldn't check it because the fiddle doesn't work in this scenario. But, I am sure you can fix that. Just see if "t" and "l" are same or not. You might need to tweak that a little depending on your use-case. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('.sub-menu a').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if(target.split('#')[1].length && target.split('#')[0] == window.location.pathname ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var targetelement = $('#' + target.split('#')[1]);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: targetelement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

this way if you are on the current page as the internal anchor, you will get smooth scrolling, else you just go to the link

Comment: I have made some edits, maybe it will work now if your links are formated like "/contact#anchor1"